# Installing dev libraries locally

Tags: debian, software-installation, libraries, development

I need to install `libpng-dev` locally on a system where I do not have `sudo` access This is required to compile a C application. What is the best way to proceed with this? Can this be installed from source?

Comment: Yes, it can be installed from source. ( `apt-get source libpng-dev`)

Comment: It can be done, however if you improve your question for what you need it, we can give a more useful and interesting answer.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Updated: To compile C code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is far more convenient from the sysadmin (and often from the developer) point of view to install development libraries using the distribution packages, such is not essencial. Depending also on the application and language, there might be several alternative ways of doing it.

In this case, you can download the .tar.gz files from the project home at http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html

Depending on the package, the make/configure files might or might not detect the library after you compile it.

The specific steps how to do it might be out-of-scope/topic here.